# Using typescript to access first item of the array, but the browser return the property undefined

Tags: typescript, angular

I write a `getFooterContent` method and i want to show data that through `getFooterContent`, but I have the following mistake:

platform-browser.umd.js:1900

> ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of
>   undefined

```
getFooterContent(){
    return this.homepageService
                         .getFooter()
                         .then(content => this.footerContent = content)
                         .catch(error => this.error = error);
}

ngOnInit(){
    this.getFooterContent();
    console.log(this.footerContent);
}
```

and my html code

```
<footer class="c-footer">
<div class="c-footer--service">
    <span>{{ footerContent[0].content}}</span>
    <span>{{ footerContent[1] }}</span>
</div>
<h1>{{ footerContent[2] }}</h1>
<div class="c-footer__version">
    <p>{{ footerContent[3] }}</p>
    <p>{{ footerContent[4] }}</p>
</div>
```

`this.footerContent` first prints `[]`

and second prints

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
0:Object content:"253548" desc:"service_tel"
```

but i don't know why `footerContent[0].content` returns undefined?

Comment: You are trying to show the content before it is loaded. Use ngIf and a boolean variable to show the content only after the content has been loaded.

Comment: yeah,first i also think the content is null before it is loaded ,and i use ngIf,but   when i use content in ngif ,it still print error,next i want to hasOwnproperty,but it still not work,so i haven't use ngIf

Answer (score 3):

Like explained by @JukkaL

```
<template [ngIf]="footerContent">
  <footer class="c-footer">
  <div class="c-footer--service">
    <span>{{ footerContent[0].content}}</span>
    <span>{{ footerContent[1] }}</span>
  </div>
  <h1>{{ footerContent[2] }}</h1>
  <div class="c-footer__version">
    <p>{{ footerContent[3] }}</p>
    <p>{{ footerContent[4] }}</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if content exist:

```
 <footer class="c-footer" *ngIf="footerContent.length > 4">
    <div class="c-footer--service">
        <span>{{ footerContent[0].content}}</span>
        <span>{{ footerContent[1] }}</span>
    </div>
    <h1>{{ footerContent[2] }}</h1>
    <div class="c-footer__version">
        <p>{{ footerContent[3] }}</p>
        <p>{{ footerContent[4] }}</p>
    </div>
```